# Product Revenue versus Revenue in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, transactions

On our online shopping cart, some products are not being attributed to the "Product Revenue" metric in Google Analytics. I understand that if a product is not assigned to a product category, it will be counted under "Revenue" but not "Product Revenue". In this case, it appears that the products are indeed assigned properly:

```
_gaq.push(['sec._addTrans',
    '91195800', // transaction ID - required
    'nature',  // affiliation or store name
    '81.01',          // total - required
    '0', // tax
    '0', // shipping
    'Stoney Creek',       // city
    'ON',     // state or province
    'CA'             // country

            _gaq.push(['sec._addItem',
         '91195800',           // transaction ID - required
         'ADULT - ADV',           // SKU/code - required
         'Product A',        // product name
         'Attraction Pass', 
         '49.946902654867',          // unit price - required
         '1'               // quantity - required
        ]);
                _gaq.push(['sec._addItem',
         '91195800',           // transaction ID - required
         'UNKNOWN',           // SKU/code - required
         'Product B',        // product name
         'Attraction Pass', 
         '6.9911504424779',          // unit price - required
         '1'               // quantity - required
        ]);
                _gaq.push(['sec._addItem',
         '91195800',           // transaction ID - required
         'ADULT - ADV',           // SKU/code - required
         'Product C',        // product name
         'Attraction Pass', 
         '14.752212389381',          // unit price - required
         '1'               // quantity - required
        ]);
```

I realize there is a second error here in that the unit prices do not include tax, where the total transaction value does, so our two totals won't match there. But the difference right now is far more than just the tax.

For example, yesterday we are seeing $3,299.54 in Product Revenue but $3,932.79 in Revenue. The tax difference would only be $428.94. These are all ticket goods so no shipping costs involved.

I can actually find some of these transactions in our shopping cart backend, where I see 4 x Product A, 4 x Product B in a transaction, but Google Analytics is showing only 4 x Product A for that transaction. The Revenue metric is correct, but the Product Revenue is wrong--clicking into the transaction the Product B's are just missing.

I obviously can't go back in time to check the source code when that customer checked out, but the code above is from a test today. Unfortunately the transaction has yet to show up in GA to see what was counted and what wasn't, but is there something in that code there that would cause an issue?

Edit: The transaction is now showing in Google Analytics and I can confirm that in the above code, Product A did not get counted as an actual product. Does it matter that the SKU is the same between those two items in the code? Would that cause GA to overwrite Product A with Product C because of the same SKU?

Answer (score 2):

Figured this out. SKUs must be unique. So, in my example, the third product is overwriting the first product in this transaction.